# Plotting different shapes for data points belonging to different groups in R

Tags: r, plot, missing-data, pch

I am trying to plot the first two columns against each other of a matrix Y, and assigning different data points different shapes and colors according to which group they belong to in the 12th column of my data set. Below is my code:

```
 X <- as.matrix(course[,1:11])
 S <- cov(X)
 l <- eigen(S)$values
 e <- eigen(S)$vector
 Y <- X %*% e

plot(Y[,1:2],
     xlab = "PC1",
     ylab = "PC2",
     pch = c(1, 17, 8)[as.numeric(course[,12])],  # different 'pch' types 
     main = "Plot of first 2 Principle Components",
     col = c(1, 8, 1)[as.numeric(course[,12])]
     )
```

"course" is the data set I'm working with, and Y is the matrix i'm interested in using for my plot. However one of the groups which i'm basing my labeling on is basically missing values or "NA". I can't use as.numeric() since this does not treat "NA" values as numeric.

When i run the code from the plot, I get two set of values, and it completely ignores the ones for NA.

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a vector of `pch` values prior to calling `plot()`.  You could do this with [?ifelse](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html), for example.  Most likely, it will be convenient to have the category with the `NA`s as the final *else*, so that you don't need a complicated matching argument.  Store this in a variable (you could call it `myPch`), and then use that variable in your function call.  That is,

```
# assuming there are 3 courses: "A", "B", & "C", but some C's are NA's
myPch <- ifelse(course[,12]=="A", 1, ifelse(course[,12]=="B", 17, 8) )
plot(..., pch=myPch, ...)
```

Comment: But pch is a plot argument, how do I go about specifying a vector assigning specific pch's to different values.

Also, I tried the if else argument in this manner:
course[,12] <- ifelse(is.na(course[,12]),0,course[,12])

but it still doesn't work. I tried relabeling it as "missing" instead of "0" but no luck. I only get two different types of points, whereas I want three.

Comment: You haven't really provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), so I'm limited in what I can show you, but I'll try to make up something & we'll see if it's enough to get the idea across.

Comment: course <- read.table("course_happy_nomiss.txt", header = TRUE)
levels(course$Year) <- list(MSc_4 = c("MSc", "4"), "3" = c("3"))


> course[,12]
 [1] 3     3     MSc_4 MSc_4 <NA>  3     MSc_4 MSc_4 3     3     3     3     3     3     3    
[16] 3     3     3     MSc_4 MSc_4 MSc_4 3     3     3     3     3     <NA>  MSc_4 3     MSc_4
[31] 3     3     3     3     3     MSc_4 3     3     <NA>  <NA>  3     MSc_4 MSc_4 MSc_4 3    
[46] MSc_4 <NA>  3     3     3     MSc_4 MSc_4 <NA>  3     3     MSc_4 <NA>  <NA>  MSc_4 MSc_4
[61] MSc_4 MSc_4 3    
Levels: MSc_4 3

Comment: that's all i got. also i noticed that the ifelse command i included returns numerical values for all my values, despite me specifying it for NA values only

Comment: You want the `ifelse` command to output numerical values only. Specifically, you want it to output the numbers for the symbols that you want to use. You should use it like the way I wrote it, just substitute the actual values for "A", "B" & "C". NB, I don't quite follow your output above, do you have 2 different values coding for the same course?

Comment: I think I solved it using this:

course[,12] <- ifelse(is.na(course[,12]),3,course[,12])

now the plot code i used above works